# Is there a fast (and unsafe) way to downcast pointers without checking?

Tags: c++, casting, rtti

I want to downcast a base class pointer to a derived class pointer.

I know that dynamic cast is costly so I want to avoid it. In my case, I am fully aware of the actual class the pointer in question points to. Is there a faster way to downcast it than dynamic casting?

I tried to use `static_cast` but it won't apply here, because there is virtual inheritance in my class hierarchy.

Update:

Thanks for the comments, I now realize that those dynamic cast is not likely to be the bottleneck of the whole program so it is almost a waste of time trying to optimize it.

Comment: *I know that dynamic cast is costly so I want to avoid it.* You've actually profiled your code and found that dynamic casts are performance bottlenecks?  If not, you're engaging in premature optimization and writing code that's more complex, when in all likelihood the performance "problem" you're spending a lot of effort to avoid won't even make a measurable difference in your code's performance. How many nanoseconds does it take to determine "this `foo` is actually a `bar`, cast is safe!"? Use a dynamic cast, and change it **only** after actual evidence **proves** it's a performance problem.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I've read [this post](http://www.nerdblog.com/2006/12/how-slow-is-dynamiccast.html), according to it, a simple cast could cost 100 cycles or so (besides, my class hierarchy is way more complex than his). If that is true, this is unacceptable for me (I am very sure of it). But thanks for the advice, I will try to implement the code first and analyze the runtime result.

Comment: If performance is the primary concern, you could always have the subclass set a void-pointer in the base class as a member-variable, which you could later downcast via reinterpret_cast<> at no runtime-cost when needed.  All very unsafe, of course.

Comment: *this is unacceptable for me (I am very sure of it)*  You **can't** be "sure of it" if you haven't both **measured** it and found that **it actually makes a difference**.  **Both** of those are necessary before you can be "sure of it".  I'll put it this way:  no one who has actually done performance optimization of real-world software would **ever** say they were "sure of it" about any piece of code being an actual performance bottleneck without actual data. And if it's not an actual performance bottleneck, it won't matter at all. Because today's CPUs aren't simple at all.

Comment: (cont) And even if you *do* find it's a performance bottleneck that actually measurably impacts performance, it may not matter anyway.  "Hey, if I redo this simple, easy-to-maintain, bug-free code into something complex, bug-prone, and unsafe we can reduce run time from 5 minutes to 4 minutes!"  "BFD.  We're required to run in under 30 minutes.  Stop wasting your time."

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks for the advice, I've edited the question accordingly

Comment: Please unaccept my answer. It is incorrect when base classes are virtual as in your example. This changes the bits on implicit up conversion.

Comment: @doug Thanks for your notice. I did my own experiment based on your answer and get the correct results so I accept it. Guess I have to design the test cases more carefully

Answer (score 3):

It does seem that this is exactly what virtual methods are for. Appropriate use of virtual methods eliminates most needs of dynamic casting. And it even works with virtual inheritance.

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

class Derived;

class Base {

public:
    virtual Derived *to_derived()
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Nope");
    }
};

class Derived : virtual public Base {
public:
    Derived *to_derived() override
    {
        return this;
    }
};

class DerivedAgain : public Derived
{
};

int main()
{
    DerivedAgain kit_and_kaboodle;

    Base *p=&kit_and_kaboodle;


    std::cout << (p->to_derived() ? "it works\n":"no it doesn't\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Add a `const` overload, for const-correctness, if needed.

Comment: It's a single dispatch through a pointer, without any conditional checks. Which will be much faster than a search of an internal multi-link tree structure that represents a class hierarchy, with multiple checks and comparisons, that makes mincemeat of CPU's branch prediction logic.

Answer (score 0):

`reinterpret_cast<>` is the answer to the basic question of what will downcast without any dynamic checks. It's the strongest (i.e. least-safe) cast this side of a C-style cast.